# You have a coin that shows tails with probability $0.125.$ You play a game where you flip the coin until tail appears for the $5th$ time.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, binomial-distribution

You have a coin that shows tails with probability $0.125.$ You play a game where you flip the coin until tail appears for the $5th$ time. Let $M$ denote the number of flips in this game.

$b)$ Compute $E[M]$

$c)$ Compute $P[M=5]$ and $P[M=6]$

**My Working:**

Let $X$ be random variable represent the number of tails occured then $X$~$BIN(0.125)$ with $p=0.125$ be probability success. Let $M$ be total number of trials, then pdf is given by:

$f(x)$=$M \choose 5 $ $0.125^{5}$$(1-0.125)^{M-5}$

My questions is from here how do I find $E(M)$, since we find expectation of random variable which is $X$ here. May be I am making mistake in constructing pdf. Once I have pdf it is easy to answer both questions. please guide me in this matter.

Comment: How many flips for one tail? For five tails, just apply linearity of expectation.

Comment: not mentioned. I have written whole question here

Comment: I know it is not mentioned. I am asking you if you can find how many flips for one tail.

Comment: No I can't. Please guide me

Comment: @Ameer786: This is a [negative binomial][1], thus 

$$P(X=n)=\binom{n-1}{5-1}0.125^5\cdot0.875^{n-5}$$

where $n=5,6,7,\dots$

with mean

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{5}{0.125}=40$$


  [1]: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/11/11.5

Comment: Thanks. I just solved by myself also. Thank you....can you look at this and guide me in this question, link is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4193225/anna-and-bert-choose-independently-and-uniformly-at-random-a-number-in-1-2